# Export GPX route from leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, gpx, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm trying to find a way of producing a GPX string from a Leaflet map so I can then save it into my DB. I am using Leaflet Routing Machine to create the route and then display it on an embedded map. So far, I found many ways to import a GPX to Leaflet but I cannot figure out a way to do the opposite.

So far, my (simplified) code to display the map and generate the route is as it follows:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>




<div id="map" class="map"></div>
        



<style>
        .map {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            justify-content: right;         
        }
</style>



<script>
            var map = L.map('map').
            setView([40.416729,-3.703339], 5);
                
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
            
            L.Routing.control({
                routeWhileDragging: true,
                geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()    
            }).addTo(map);
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created recently the small Leaflet Plugin [L.ConvertCoords](https://github.com/Falke-Design/L.ConvertCoords), which allows you to import (parse) and export (convert) layers in different Formats:

```
var gpxString = L.ConvertCoords.GPX.convert(layer);
```

In the back I use the library [toGPX](https://github.com/tyrasd/togpx)

Comment: how can I initialise the Layer variable to my route once I generate it? Bear in mind that the map is blank(as in, no routes) until I search for directions and it generates a route...

Comment: You can use the events `routefound` `routeselected` to get the coords and then create a Polyline: `var layer = L.polyline(latlngs);` [Tutorial]'(https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/integration/)